# Spring re-injection concept

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I have just read the Spring documentation on constructor and setter dependency injection. 
However, the whole concept of DI still confuses me a lot. In particular, the process still seems pretty limited or constrained to me.

I understand the idea of a third party (Spring) that assigns and wires object's dependencies altogether. But if we only supply dependencies through constructor (init time) and setters (init then do some property setting), then how can we reconfigure or re-inject new beans later ?

I mean for example bean `A` has reference to bean `B`. Tbrough constructor or setter injection we can do just as what we know from the docs. But then what if later in the application we need bean `A` to obtain a reference to some other object/bean `C` ?

Do we need to load new application context from a new Spring XML config file, or another approach ? This operation may be performed multiple times, so it should be easy to config. One thing I'm surprised is that such a common task is not mentioned in most tutorials or explanations on Spring DI. Maybe I need other keywords (currently I'm using Spring re-injection).

Answer (score 0):

You can inject ApplicationContext in A

```
private ApplicationContext context;

public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContect context) {
    this.context = context;
}
```

then you will have access to any bean at any time

```
...
    C c =context.getBean(C.class);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Wherever you require ApplicationContext in your application, implement that class with `ApplicationContextAware` interface.

Say here

```
 public class CalenderService implements ApplicationContextAware{

    private ApplicationContext context;//declare this so you can use it

 }
```

As it is interface you need to overide its method

```
public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext context){
   this.context=context; // here ApplicationContext gets injected.
}
```

And use this context wherever you want.

Answer (score 0):

Context driven frameworks like Guice, HK2 or CDI tend to use proxies when they inject services whose lifecycles differ from the lifecycle of the service they are being injected into.  Then when a service changes underneath the proxy, the proxy just looks up the new instance and uses that for subsequent calls.  There are other reasons that frameworks like that use proxies, for example in order to avoid services that have expensive initialization costs.